# greenDAO: abstracting out the database implementation

Tags: android, orm, greendao, spatialite, sqlcipher-android

I want to use my own custom SQLiteDatabase implementation in greenDAO based on something very similar to sqlcipher. I've seen a newly committed branch "DbAbstraction" of greenDAO. This exactly what I need. I am asking the authors: Is there some plan to merge it with master? I know i can fork the whole greenDAO and patch it myself but i wish to make the things clean and compatible with future versions of greenDAO. Patching after every new version doesn't look nice. Any hints how to proceed?